# Redirecting in Admin Site

Tags: django, django-admin, django-templates

I have an app called CMS with Category and Article. Quite simple.

I overwrite `app_index.html` to enable ajax-based drag-n-drop ordering and to move articles from one category to another.

Now I would like to redirect after saving/deleting an article or a category to cms' `app_index.html` instead of the model's `change_list.html`. How can this be done?

Thanks

```
class Category(models.Model):
    order = models.IntegerField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    text  = models.TextField()

class Article(models.Model):
    published  = models.BooleanField(default=None)
    images     = generic.GenericRelation(Photo)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    text  = models.TextField()
    order = models.IntegerField(blank = True, null = True)
```

---

Daniel's answer did half the job: Redirect after changing the articles and categories.

---

A not very elegant solution: Redirection in urls.py

```
def redirect_cms(response):
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/admin/cms/')

urlpatterns += patterns('',
    (r'^admin/cms/article/$',redirect_cms),
```

any other idea?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your `admin` subclass, override the `response_change` and/or the `response_add` methods. These are called after the admin form is saved ,for existing and new instances respectively, and are responsible for returning the `HttpResponseRedirect` that currently takes you to the change_list page.

Take a look at the original code in `django.contrib.admin.options` to see what you need to do.

**Edit**: There are two ways a deletion can take place: as a result of an action on the `change_list` page, in which case you can use the `response_action` method; or as a result of a deletion on the change form, in which case unfortunately there is no equivalent method. One way of dealing with this might be to override the `change_form.html` template for the app, and remove the deletion link, so that the only way to delete is via the changelist. Not ideal by any means.

Comment: or at least half answered: How to redirect after delete?

Answer (score 5):

The question is already answered, but the problem of redirect after delete is not covered. Maybe the following solution will be helpful for somebody. Django's `ModelAdmin` class has got `delete_view` member function. It does two things:

1. If `POST` is not defined, shows *Deletion confirmation* page. If you confirm and click *Delete*, it generates a `POST` request.
2. As `POST` is now defined, the view deletes the requested items and returns an `HttpResponseRedirect` to changelist (or admin index, if the user doesn't have a permission to change).

So, let's override this as follows.

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def delete_view(self, request, object_id, extra_context=None):
        """Redirect to website index page on delete."""

        response = super(MyAdmin, self).delete_view(request, object_id, extra_context)

        # Use our own redirect
        if isinstance(response, HttpResponseRedirect):
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/') # Any URL here

        return response
```

It seems working for me under Django 1.6.

Comment: Nice solution for Django 1.6

Comment: Still working in Django-2.2, although [`response_delete`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.response_delete) is the most suitable method to override, as per @Patrick [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24237153/2996101).

Answer (score 4):

As of Django 1.7, there is a `response_delete` method which you can override on the admin object. See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.response_delete)

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def response_delete(self, request, obj_display):
        return HttpResponseRedirect("my_url")
```